# FTP Browser (with content viewer) Android App

Tags: android, file-management, ftp, github, documentation-viewer

I have readyshare on my netgear router, and need an android app to view the files on readyshare.

I know about some file explorers (ES Explorer, etc) and they are not free apps for the FTP access. I'm looking for a free app that allows me to browse the FTP folder and view/stream the content on the readyshare flash drive.

Filetypes: mp4, docx, jpg, png and txt files.

Are there any github php projects that I could convert to apk via app-making-softwares for this purpose.

My FTP server that I need to access is: `ftp://readyshare.routerlogin.net/shares`

Comment: Sure you have [looked well enough](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman#group_156)? At F-Droid, there're e.g. [Ghost Commander](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.ghostsq.commander/) and [Amaze File Manager](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.amaze.filemanager/) as file managers with networking capabilities. Does none of these two fit your other requirements?

Comment: Amaze file manager only has a ftp server. I need an ftp client with file viewer. Simple ftp client would also be alright, but with a file streaming viewer.

Comment: I didn't try either (hence just the comment). So what about the Ghost?

Comment: Haven't tried ghost commander. It's got smb too! Thanks! I'll try it out tomorow!

Comment: It might be overblown for you and really too much - but you mentioned  a PHP project that could provide same functionality you might want to check [NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/) and the likes. all have also FTP options. But like I said, might be an overkill for you

Answer (score 1):

Browsers handle FTP links just fine, as well as content delivered over FTP protocol.  So ... Firefox, Chrome, whatever you prefer...

Comment: This doesn't help. Cause I need a file viewer with ftp access.

Comment: @mk117 what do you mean by file viewer ? most file browsers will eventually open the documents in a dedicated app - just like what you will have with any simple browser..